# Shortcut keys to switch between path and shape section of pen tool in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool, shortcuts, path

I use pen tool a lot to create custom shapes and sometimes add a new path to the existing vector mask, but I only know to choose at the tool bar to switch between the two. Is there any quicker way to switch between the path and shape section with shortcut keys?

**Edit:**

I would like to create new custom shapes and edit existing paths without leaving the pen tool. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess you could bind a button to an action that will reproduce recorded shape of selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I think I found the way.

Because of my bad memory caused by working late in the night, I could not remember I could **press control** and **select part of the path** of the custom shape which I just created. Then I could do all the editing I wanted, including add a new point to the path, moving points, etc.

(And I have mixing that up with switching between Shape or Path at the tool bar. Silly me.)

Thanks for your attentions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Tap the <kbd>u</kbd> key for the **Shape Tool**

Tap the <kbd>p</kbd> key for the **Pen Tool**

These shortcuts are displayed next to the tool in the tool flyouts.

### EDIT:

Custom shapes are created with the pen or shape tools. If you mean you want to choose "**Define a Custom Shape**" from the menu using a shortcut, then choose `Edit > Keyboard` Shortcuts and set a custom shortcut for the menu item. That's all there is to it.

Comment: No. I mean create custom shapes not predefined shapes.